# manual g++ install: endless dependencies

Tags: c, ubuntu, g++, dependencies, dpkg

I am trying to install g++ as necessary to compile and install a Broadcom wireless and wired network drivers. Which means, no way to use apt-get or aptitude commands. So, I downloaded from another computer having already internet connection the g++-4.2-multilib_4.2.4-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb, among other packages.

During the install it gives:

```
# dpkg -i g++*
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration
g++-4.2-multilib depends on g++-4.2 (= 4.2.4-1ubuntu3); however:
Package gcc-4.2-base is not installed
```

But here the trick questions is... whenever I install a dependency, a dozen of other dependencies emerges. It looks like never going to end. Any suggestion how to bring that dependencies under control? I already burned two days on it... and does not look any better yet.

All comments and suggestions are welcome and highly appreciated!

Comment: Since this question is not related to programming/software development , it does not belong in SO , these installation problems ,on linux, are better addressed at [superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Or [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/). See [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: @Eliah-Kagan Very useful your suggestion! It helped with some other extra dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `sudo apt-get install build-essential` --- a meta-package which get you what you need.

Comment: Great! It just worked like a charm....|:0), Now I go into development... compiling, debugging and testing mode.